# Wireless Kernel Module Not Loaded

Tags: centos, wifi

I did a CentOS 7 x86_64 minimal install on my computer with an AMD x64 processor.
I am now attempting to set up WIFI. The wireless driver iwl4965 from [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/) is installed but is not showing as being loaded into the kernel when I run the following commands:

```
lsmod
```

and

```
modprobe
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install firmware

```
yum install iwl4965-firmware
```

Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file , and comment the `blacklist iwl4965` line

```
# blacklist iwl4965
```

Reboot your system and start the network services:

```
chkconfig NetworkManager on
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager start
```

Comment: I cannot use yum because I dont have connection to the internet (I dont have an ethernet cable accessible right now) , also there is no blacklist file in /etc/modprobe.d/

Comment: If the `iwl4965` is installed you can skip the install step.

Comment: I tried all of these steps and it is still showing the module as not being loaded